# Google Cloud Storage upload 10gb filesize error in Cyberduck

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a big file (9gb) to google storage using Cyberduck.
The login and transfer with small files work. However for this file I'm getting the following error:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:34 GMT
x-goog-project-id: 674064471933
x-goog-api-version: 2
Authorization: OAuth SECRET_KEY
Host: storage.googleapis.com:443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Cyberduck/4.4.4 (Mac OS X/10.9) (x86_64)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 340
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:35 GMT
Expires: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:35 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 16 2014 16:50:43 (1397692243)
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
GET /vibetracestorage/?prefix=eventsall.csv&uploads HTTP/1.1
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:35 GMT
x-goog-api-version: 2
Authorization: OAuth SECRET_KEY
Host: storage.googleapis.com:443
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Cyberduck/4.4.4 (Mac OS X/10.9) (x86_64)
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 173
Date: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:36 GMT
Expires: Wed, 30 Apr 2014 08:47:36 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 16 2014 16:50:43 (1397692243)
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to that log you posted, you're placing a GET to "https://storage.googleapis.com/vibetracestorage/?prefix=eventsall.csv&uploads".

I don't know what that "uploads" parameter tacked onto the end is, but it's not a valid parameter for requesting a bucket listing (which is what that request does).

If you place that request by hand, you'll see this error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message><Details>Invalid query parameter(s): [uploads]</Details></Error>
```

Also, as a general point of good practice, do not post logs that contain your full Authorization header. That is a very, very bad idea. You may want to delete this question, although those credentials will expire (and perhaps already have).

Comment: it's the error log from CyberDuck, I have not done it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interoperability issue. In Cyberduck, when connected to S3, multipart uploads are supported as defined by Amazon S3. The request with the `uploads` parameter is used to find already existing in progress multipart uploads for the same target object that can be resumed.

Make sure to choose *Google Storage* and not *S3* in the protocol dropdown list in the bookmark or connection prompt. Multipart uploads should then be disabled.